# Angular Not applying animation styles to ngShow/Hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Literally copy pasted from the angular API, but won't work on my machine? I've read ngAnimate was depreciated a while back. Currently using 1.2.3 but can't get the animations to load?

Is the Syntax on the Angular API incorrect?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
            Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"><br/>
            <div>
              Show:
              <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="checked">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> I show up when your checkbox is checked.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              Hide:
              <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-hide="checked">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> I hide when your checkbox is checked.
              </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.animate-show {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
  transition:all linear 0.5s;
  line-height:20px;
  opacity:1;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
  line-height:0;
  opacity:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}

.check-element {
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}
```

Comment: did you include file `angular-animate.js ` and add as module dependency?

Comment: No, is this still required even though its depreciated? I tried to install a version for 1.2.3 and got an npm error.

Comment: yes is required with older versions like you are using

Comment: If you want to submit that as the answer I can give you the question. Cheers